# How to calculate percentage and average of test scores in a 2D list without using libraries like pandas or numpy

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv data of a test scores. The current program is able to read this data into a 2D list with the test out of marks. I later created a function to remove test out of row so only the student's marks can be displayed. I'm now struggling to write a function which can print the scores so that each student's percentage appears on a separate line of output.

**My code so far**

```
def getData():

   with open("testscores.csv","r") as file:
    lineArray = file.read().splitlines()
    matrix = []
    for line in lineArray:
      matrix.append(line.split(","))

    return matrix

def fullScores(matrix):
  matrix.pop(0)

  return matrix

def printscores(matrix):

  for counter in matrix:
    for values in counter:
      print(values, end= " ")
    print()
  

matrix = getData()
matrix = fullScores(matrix)
print()
printscores(matrix)
```

**output**

```
Bob 10 9 7 8 10 9 9 9 10 8 8 10 9 9 
Sue 8 8 8 9 4 8 9 7 8 3 10 10 7 9
Jan 6 6 0 5 7 9 4 7 8 5 7 1 5 9
Sam 8 8 8 7 7 7 9 9 9 9 8 9 10 8
Tom 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 9 9 9 9
```

**expected output**

```
Bob 100% 90% 70% 80% 100% 90% 90% 90% 100% 80% 80% 100% 90% 90% Average = 89%
Sue 80% 80% 80% 90% 40% 80% 90% 70% 80% 30% 100% 100% 70% 90% Average = 77%
...
```

**csv data**

```
Testoutof,10,11,12,11,10,11,9,10,10,11,10,12,10,9
Bob,10,9,7,8,10,9,9,9,10,8,8,10,9,9
Sue,8,8,8,9,4,8,9,7,8,3,10,10,7,9
Jan,6,6,0,5,7,9,4,7,8,5,7,1,5,9
Sam,8,8,8,7,7,7,9,9,9,9,8,9,10,8
Tom,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,9,9,9,9
```

Comment: Why do you just discard the first row? That is what tells you the number you should use to calculate the percentage for each column. It doesn't look like you've tried to calculate the percentage and average. Please make an attempt yourself before asking. If you've already made an attempt, you probably have a more specific question than "how do I do it?", so please ask that question.

Comment: Right. It was just to avoid showing out of marks to the user but that's okay we can keep it. Any hint or suggesion how to calculate percentage and average? Thanks.

Comment: `how to calculate percentage` - divide each score by 10 then multiply by 100.  `how to calculate ... average?` - sum the scores then divide by the number of scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `list comprehension` can give you the same result, without any *function* definition:

```
file=open("testscores.csv","r")
matrix=[line.strip().split(",") for line in file.readlines()[1:]]

for row in matrix:
  data=[int(i)*10 for i in row[1:]]
  print(row[0], "% ".join(map(str, data))+"%",  "Average =", sum(data)//len(data),"%")
```

**Output**:

```
Bob 100% 90% 70% 80% 100% 90% 90% 90% 100% 80% 80% 100% 90% 90% Average = 89 %
Sue 80% 80% 80% 90% 40% 80% 90% 70% 80% 30% 100% 100% 70% 90% Average = 77 %
Jan 60% 60% 0% 50% 70% 90% 40% 70% 80% 50% 70% 10% 50% 90% Average = 56 %
Sam 80% 80% 80% 70% 70% 70% 90% 90% 90% 90% 80% 90% 100% 80% Average = 82 %
Tom 90% 90% 90% 90% 90% 90% 90% 90% 90% 100% 90% 90% 90% 90% Average = 90 %
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are many ways to do this, but here is one possible solution. I used only Lists and Tuple. Using dictionaries you would have a more elegant way accessing data.

```
students = []
reference_scores = []

def get_data():
    with open("./data/testscores.csv", "r") as file:
        lineArray = file.read().splitlines()        

        for line in lineArray:
            raw_data = line.split(",")
            name = raw_data[0]
            scores = []
            percentages = []
            average_percentage = 0

            if name != 'Testoutof':
                scores = raw_data[1:]

                for index, score in enumerate(scores):
                    percentage = get_percentage(int(score), int(reference_scores[index]))
                    average_percentage += percentage
                    percentages.append(percentage)
                average_percentage //= len(scores)
                students.append( (name, percentages, average_percentage) )
            else:
                reference_scores = raw_data[1:]
    return students

def get_percentage(score, reference):
    return (score * 100) // reference

def print_scores(data):
    for obj in data:
        score_string = ''
        for score in obj[1]:
            score_string += f'{score}% '    
        print(f'{obj[0]} {score_string} Average = {obj[2]}')

students = get_data()
print_scores(students)

# Output
Bob 100% 81% 58% 72% 100% 81% 100% 90% 100% 72% 80% 83% 90% 100%  Average = 86
Sue 80% 72% 66% 81% 40% 72% 100% 70% 80% 27% 100% 83% 70% 100%  Average = 74
Jan 60% 54% 0% 45% 70% 81% 44% 70% 80% 45% 70% 8% 50% 100%  Average = 55    
Sam 80% 72% 66% 63% 70% 63% 100% 90% 90% 81% 80% 75% 100% 88%  Average = 79 
Tom 90% 81% 75% 81% 90% 81% 100% 90% 90% 90% 90% 75% 90% 100%  Average = 87
```